# Live Server in VS Code Ubuntu does not automatically open the browser tab. Need Help

Tags: webserver, visual-studio-code, html5, web-development

I am using VS Code in Linux. The OS Details are given below

> NAME="Ubuntu" 
> VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

Here's a brief description of what the issue is -

- I installed the [Live Server Extension developed by Ritwick Dey](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server). It's a popular VS Code Extension. I tried to use it with a simple `index.html` file.
- It started `localhost` with the default `port 5050`.
- Now the problem is that I need to manually open a browser and type `localhost:5050/index.html` every time to actually view the output of the file.
- Once I do this, `Live Server` starts implementing the changes as I code them in the `index.html` file.
- So while `Live Server` does work, it does not work exactly like it is supposed to since I have to manually open the specific URL every time.
- ***For VS Code in Windows, LiveServer opens Chrome automatically as soon as I turn it on***, and then it keeps updating the output accordingly as more stuff is coded into the file in VS Code
  I'm using Chrome as my default Browser.

I have also edited the LiveServer Settings JSON file in VS Code and added these extra settings at the bottom -

```
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
```

and

```
"liveServer.settings.useLocalIp": true
```

**Note -**

I have also downloaded Microsoft Edge Beta version for Linux, and I use it as my main browser, but it is not the default browser

Comment: This is a VS Code issue from the sounds of it. Have you [submitted a bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions)? If this doesn’t work for you, there’s a chance it doesn’t work for others as well 

Comment: @guiverc what else should i include to make it clear? 

I have put a brief description of how the issue is produced.

I have also explained that it works just fine in Windows.

What exactly it is that you dont understand? The english and the order in which i have described seems just fine because one more user (matigo) was able to understand the problem.

Comment: @matigo

I dont think this is an issue with VS Code since it works fine on WIndows. But i'll still try to submit a bug report. Given how popular linux is among developers, and the fact that this extension has around 15 million downloads, I am kinda surprised this issue still persists. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is too late but same happened to me in Arcolinux. Just had to write as the launcher in settings.json file:

```
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "google-chrome-stable"
```

I left this here just in case this helps anybody else.